# Combine multiple source sets to make a decision

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, combinations, ocr, probability

I'm working on a project in which I am using `ocr-engine` and `tensorflow` to identify the **vehicle number plate** and **vehicle model** respectively. I also have a `database` which contains **Vehicle Information** (for eg, owner, number plate, vehicle brand, color, etc).

**Simple flow:**

1. Image input
2. Number plate recognition using `OCR`
3. Vehicle model (eg Hyundai,Toyota, Honda, etc) using `Tensorflow`
4. Query (2. and 3.) in `database` to **find the owner**

Now, the fact is `ocr-engine` is not 100% accurate, let's consider `INDXXXX0007` as the best result of the engine.

When I query this result in `database` I get

**Set 1**,

- Owner1 - `INDXXXX0004` (95% match)
- Owner2 - `INDXXXX0009` (95% match)

In such cases, I use `tensorflow` data to make a decision

**Set 2**, *where vehicle model shows*:

- Hyundai (95.00%)
- Honda (90.00%)

Here comes my main problem, `tensorflow` sometimes gives me *false-positive* values. For eg, the **actual vehicle is Honda** but the model shows more `confidence` for **Hyundai** (ref, Set2).

**What should be a possible way to avoid such problems or How can I combine both sets to make a decision?**